# Configure WSO2 Stratos in a private cloud

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

Trying to find out how to build a private cloud using WSO2 Stratos.  I have a small rack of computers and have successfully installed Stratos on one machine and it seems to work just fine. However, I can’t seem to figure out how to setup the other machines so that they operate in "cloud mode".

I am pretty sure I am looking at this wrong because I can’t find a scrap of documentation on how to do this, so any pointing in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a private cloud, just like you set the Stratos up in your computer. In StratosLive, the publicly hosted PaaS of Stratos, we have Amazon EC2 as our underlying infrastructure, and use [WSO2 Load Balancer](http://kkpradeeban.blogspot.com/2011/06/wso2-load-balancer.html) to load balance and auto-scale among the instances. However you might also use Eucalyptus and other cloud infrastructure instead. Once you have set up Eucalyptus or a similar private cloud infrastructure, you can set up Stratos Services separately on the instances, according to the availability of the instances.

I would suggest contacting [WSO2 Oxygen Tank Stratos Forum](http://wso2.org/forum/978) or stratos-dev mailing list (Stratos-dev@wso2.org), as they will grab the attention of the core WSO2 team pretty quicker.

Answer (score 2):

No.. you need not to pay... WSO2 Oxygen Tank Stratos Forum or stratos-dev mailing list provide free support...

Thanks...